# Забрать из объектов значение name и преобразовать в массив

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть данные, которые получаю с сервера, из этих данных надо достать только имена и прокинуть в функцию, которая засетает их

```js
export const getActorsThunkAC = () => (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('people/?page=1')
        .then(response => {
            debugger
            dispatch(setStatusAC(statuses.SUCCESS));
            dispatch(setTotalActorCountAC(response.data.count));
            dispatch(setNextPageAC(response.data.next));
            dispatch(setPreviousPageAC(response.data.previous));
            response.data.results.map(el => setActorsAC(el.name));
        })
};
[![Ответ от сервера][1]][1]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы очень лаконичны. ИМХО, пара связывающих фраз может ускорить получение ответа :).

Comment: Есть данные, которые получаю с сервера, из этих данных надо достать только имена и прокинуть в функцию, которая засетает их

Comment: Вставьте этот комментарий в текст вопроса, чтобы человек, который его читает и может ответить, не тратил свое время на "вход" в Вашу проблему

Comment: А что делает `setActorsAc` ? Можно `let arr = response.data.results.map( e => e.name );` — а уже потом с полученным массивом `arr` что-то делать...